# Limit the minimum year in DatePicker selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I'm using jQuery DatePicker to select a date on my form. I want to limit the years in that calendar in such a way that it will display the years from 1900 and up.

I tried this code:

```
$('#' + CalenderId).datepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
    autoclose: true,
    changeMonth: true, 
    changeYear: true, 
    yearRange: '1900:+0'
});
```

But it still shows the year earlier than 1900:

[image]

Is there any other way available to limit this?

Comment: please see http://jsfiddle.net/zjohnson/X6fmb/ last datepicker, it will help you

Answer (score 2):

**startDate: '-30y',
endDate: '+0y'**

This will help you to restrict year 
eg: if current year is is 2020 then 
it will allow to select start year as 2020-30 = 1990
and end year as 2020

here is the code:

```
$("#year").datepicker({
        autoclose: !0,
        yearHighlight: !0,
        format: "yyyy",
        viewMode: "years",
        minViewMode: "years",
        startDate: '-30y',
        endDate: '+0y'
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

The `yearRange` is only for the list of years. To limit the entered date itself, you need to use `minDate` and `maxDate`. Example:

```
yearRange: "-150Y:-10Y",
minDate: "-150Y",
maxDate: "-10Y",
```

Using `yearRange: "1900:+0"` will only give you years 1900+.

Comment: I tried using `yearRange: "1900:+0"` but i still can see -100 value